# How to read this image server side in java ( Blackberry 10 front end)

Tags: java, image

> ```
>  void ApplicationUI::post(const QString& fullName, const QString& email,
>     const QString& password)
>   {
> connection = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); // this can be also in app constructor
> QUrl url("http://www.rws.rajaspot.com/rs_usermanagementclient.php");
> QUrl postParams;
> postParams.addQueryItem("method", "rsnewuser");
> postParams.addQueryItem("fullName", fullName);
> postParams.addQueryItem("email", email);
> postParams.addQueryItem("password", password);
>      if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
>           qDebug() << "open ok";
>      else
>           qDebug() << "open FAILED";
>     postParams.addQueryItem("imageFile", file->readAll());
> QNetworkRequest req(url);
> req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> QNetworkReply *reply = connection->post(req, postParams.encodedQuery());
> connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(postFinished()));
>      }
>     void ApplicationUI::postFinished()
>     {
> QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
> if (!reply->error()){
>     QString response = reply->readAll();
>     qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "RESPONSE" << response;
>     emit postDone(response);
> }else{
>     qDebug() << "ErrorCode" << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt() << endl << \
>             "ErrorString" << reply->errorString();
>     emit error(reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt(), reply->errorString());
> }
> reply->deleteLater();
> connection->deleteLater(); // this only need if is connection declared inside post function
>       }
> ```

I am sending an image as param, how can I read this in server side java? File is of type qfile ...and assume the image is .png or .jpeg..
I am using this in bb10..to try and upload image to the server.

Comment: It is somehow unclear what your problem is. IMO you need to extend your question a bit - what do you want to do on the server side with the image, what kind of server are you using, which java server technology is on the server? Is it just a http server or is there some API you can use?

Comment: Am using spring frame work, I just want a java sample..on how can i read the imagefile once the api  myurl is called